# Excel Data Table - References change if underlying view changes

Tags: excel

I have a data table in Excel connected to a view in MSSQL. The SQL in Excel is executing a SELECT * against the view.

I've setup a number of formulas to reference the table i.e.

```
=AVERAGE(table[Field A])
=AVERAGE(table[Field B])
=AVERAGE(table[Field C])
```

If I change the definition of the view and insert a field between B and C in the view, the formulas automatically update as follows:

```
=AVERAGE(table[Field A])
=AVERAGE(table[Field B])
=AVERAGE(table[Field X])
```

Is there any way to stop this behavior or lock in the formulas?

Comment: you could just reference the range directly in excel, like `=Average($A:$A)` or `=Average($A$1:$A$100)` The dollars signs will lock the cell reference from shifting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Scott. I definitely don't want to do this as I'm trying to move away from using references like this. It's much more user friendly to write the formula using the column names of the table.

Comment: or is it? Sounds like it may not be that friendly. But I know what you mean? I haven't used Tables that much, so I don't know if a locking feature exists, like the `$` sign with ranges. Best to you on finding a solution to do that, though. That said, have you tried to play with the Table properties?